# Put values into array using foreach loop

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, casting, ascii

I have this method that accepts a String, counts "invisible" ASCII characters (meaning literally invisible to the naked eye e.g. space), and returns the total count of such characters.

So far I have:

- Converted the String input to char array
- Casted each char of the array to int using foreach

  ```
  public static int getInvisibleCharactersCount(String inputWords) {
      int invisibleCharacters = 0;
      int decimalEquivalent = 0;

      char[] caInputWords = inputWords.toCharArray(); // Convert String input to char array

      for(char asciiChar: caInputWords) {
          decimalEquivalent = (int) asciiChar; // Cast each char of the array to int

          // Put ints into an intArray
      }

      for(int ctr = 0; ctr < intArray.length; ctr++) {
          if((decimalEquivalent >= 0 && decimalEquivalent < 33) ||
          (decimalEquivalent >= 127 && decimalEquivalent < 161)) {
              invisibleCharacters++;
          }
      }

      return invisibleCharacters;
  }
  ```

  How do I put the casted ints of the foreach into an intArray?

Comment: Why do you cast to int? a char is already a number...

Comment: Why don't you use ArrayList?

Comment: @assylias Though it does not technically answer the question, that was good info. I am currently learning casting.

Comment: @hemanth Unfortunately, we have not yet reached that part of the lesson, although solutions using ArrayLists are also welcome. Good for advance studying.

Comment: @ohtph Okay. I have added solution using arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have used ArrayList but since you were specific about having an Int Array. You can create an int array of same size of `caInputWords` and add elements inside `foreach` loop. Check the code below

```
 public static int getInvisibleCharactersCount(String inputWords) {
    int invisibleCharacters = 0;
    int decimalEquivalent = 0;

    char[] caInputWords = inputWords.toCharArray(); // Convert String input to char array
    int[] intArray = new int[caInputWords.length]; //<<-Create an int array of size of your char array
    int i= 0; //intializing your counter
    for(char asciiChar: caInputWords) {
        decimalEquivalent = (int) asciiChar; // Cast each char of the array to int

        // Put ints into an intArray
        intArray[i] = decimalEquivalent; 
        i++; //increment counter after each iteration


    }

    for(int ctr = 0; ctr < intArray.length; ctr++) {
        if((intArray[ctr] >= 0 && intArray[ctr] < 33) ||
        (intArray[ctr] >= 127 && intArray[ctr] < 161)) {
            invisibleCharacters++;
        }
    }

    return invisibleCharacters;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have copied the entire method to ensure I did not miss anything, but unfortunately, it does not count. Entering "has two spaces" should return 2, but it always returns 0. Further assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: @ohtph I have edited just a min back? Did you check the latest one?

Comment: I have refreshed the page and copied the method again, it works now. Thank you. Out of curiosity, would putting a counter inside a foreach defeat the purpose of it?

Comment: @ohtph I'll leave that to you to decide :P Refer this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: I observe that foreach is great for accessing elements, but may not be the best for assigning values, since a counter must be maintained (might as well use the regular for-loop). I am marking your answer as accepted answer, because I did ask for foreach anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to split the `String` into a character array.  You can directly use a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputWords.length(); i++) {
    char c = inputWords.charAt(i);
    // do some struff with c
}
```

Comment: Or more simply: `for (char c : inputWords.toCharArray())`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ArrayList` for dynamically re-size

```
char[] caInputWords = inputWords.toCharArray(); // Convert String input to char array
ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(char asciiChar: caInputWords) {
    decimalEquivalent = (int) asciiChar; // Cast each char of the array to int

    // Put ints into an intArray
    intArray.add(decimalEquivalent);
}
```

Or for reqular arrays

```
char[] caInputWords = inputWords.toCharArray(); // Convert String input to char array
int[] intArray = new int[caInputWords.length];
for (int i = 0; i < caInputWords.length; i++) {
    decimalEquivalent = (int) caInputWords[i]; // Cast each char of the array to int

    // Put ints into an intArray
    intArray[i] = decimalEquivalent;
}

for(int ctr = 0; ctr < intArray.length; ctr++) {
    if((intArray[ctr] >= 0 && intArray[ctr] < 33) ||
      (intArray[ctr] >= 127 && intArray[ctr] < 161)) {
         invisibleCharacters++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have used your solution using regular arrays, but it does not count. Entering "Grumpy Cat" should yield 1 since there is 1 space. Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you, do you mean the space should not be count ?

Comment: The space must be counted. For example if I entered "has two spaces", it should return 2, since there are 2 spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much, the regular for-loop works as it should. I realize foreach here may not have been needed. I accepted another answer though, since my question did ask for foreach (to be fair). Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a collection such as a ArrayList and add to that instead. If at the end you wish to convert to an array you can do the following:

```
int[] intArray = intArrayList.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you do not know the number of i`invisible` characters before , it's best to create list.  I prefer iterating list but if you want array for further processing , following is sample code.

public static int getInvisibleCharactersCount(String inputWords) {
        int invisibleCharacters = 0;
        int decimalEquivalent = 0;

```
    char[] caInputWords = inputWords.toCharArray(); // Convert String input to char array
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer[] intArray =  null;

    for(char asciiChar: caInputWords) {
        decimalEquivalent = (int) asciiChar; // Cast each char of the array to int

        intList.add(decimalEquivalent );
    }

   intArray = new Integer[intList.size()]

   intArray = intList.toArray(intArray);

    for(int ctr = 0; ctr < intArray.length; ctr++) {
        if((decimalEquivalent >= 0 && decimalEquivalent < 33) ||
        (decimalEquivalent >= 127 && decimalEquivalent < 161)) {
            invisibleCharacters++;
        }
    }

    return invisibleCharacters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From assylias, saying a char is already an int, I realized below code yields the same result without the need to cast or create another integer array:

```
public static int getInvisibleCharactersCount(String inputWords) {
        int invisibleCharacters = 0;

        char[] caInputWords = inputWords.toCharArray();

        for(int ctr = 0; ctr < caInputWords.length; ctr++) {
            if((caInputWords[ctr] >= 0 && caInputWords[ctr] < 33) ||
              (caInputWords[ctr] >= 127 && caInputWords[ctr] < 161)) {
                 invisibleCharacters++;
            }
        }

    return invisibleCharacters;
}
```